# Encoding Decoding Golang problem: gob: duplicate type received

Tags: go, duplicates, encoder-decoder, gob

I'm trying to build a simulator of an exchange. The server builds the Order_Book struct with the orders sent from the Clients.
I want the server to send the Order_Book struct to the Client after his request. Unfortunately after the first Client decoding of the Order_Book I have the error

`gob: duplicate type received`

But (only) the second error say:

`gob: decoding into local type *int, received remote type User = struct { Name string; }`

**Server**

```
decoder := gob.NewDecoder(conn)
        // Read the message type
        var messageType int
        err := decoder.Decode(&messageType)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("\nError decoding message type: %v\n", err)
            return
        }

        switch messageType {
            case 3:// Oeder book
                

                var user_info common.User
                err := decoder.Decode(&user_info)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error decoding User for OB:", err)
                    return
                }
                fmt.Printf("Received User info for OB: %+v\n", user_info)
                
                encoder := gob.NewEncoder(conn)
                // Encode the message type
                
                err_bi := encoder.Encode(4)
                if err_bi != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("error encoding message type: %v", err_bi)
                }

                // Encode and send the order book to the client
                err_mm := encoder.Encode(OB)
                if err_mm != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error encoding order book:", err_mm)
                    //return
                }

                fmt.Println("Order book sent to client")


        }
```

**Client**

```
var exi string="n"
    for{
        
        fmt.Print("\nWanna: \n (q) Quit\n (t) Trade\n (v) See OrderBook\n\n")
        inp, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        exi = strings.TrimSpace(inp)
        
        
        if exi== "q"{                            
            fmt.Print("\n\n$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\n$       BYE!       $\n$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\n\n")
            break

        } else if exi== "t" {
            inOrd := Type_Order()

            fmt.Printf("Address of inord= %v:\t%p\n", inOrd, &inOrd)
            
            err = common.SendMessage(conn, 1, inOrd)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error sending MessageOne:", err)
                return
            }
            fmt.Printf("\nOrder sent: %v\n",inOrd)

        } else if exi== "v" {

            encoder := gob.NewEncoder(conn)

            // Encode the message type
            err := encoder.Encode(3)
            if err != nil {
                continue //fmt.Errorf("error encoding message type: %v", err)
            }
            
            // Encode and send the actual data
            err = encoder.Encode(User_info) 
            if err != nil {
                continue//fmt.Errorf("error encoding data: %v", err)
            }
            var code int
            var OB common.Order_Book

        
            decoder := gob.NewDecoder(conn)

            err__f := decoder.Decode(&code)
            if err__f != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error decoding order book type message:", err__f)
                continue
            }
            
            err_m := decoder.Decode(&OB)
            if err_m != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error decoding order book data:", err_m)
                continue
            }
            fmt.Printf("Received Order Book: %+v\n", OB)
        
            // Print the received order book
            fmt.Println("Received Order Book:")
            common.Order_Book_print(OB, common.ORDER_BOOK_LENGTH, false)

         }
```

**Client Output**

```
Wanna: 
 (q) Quit
 (t) Trade
 (v) See OrderBook

v
Error decoding order book type message: gob: duplicate type received

Wanna: 
 (q) Quit
 (t) Trade
 (v) See OrderBook

v
Error decoding order book type message: gob: decoding into local type *int, received remote type User = struct { Name string; }

Wanna:
 (q) Quit
 (t) Trade
 (v) See OrderBook

v
Error decoding order book type message: gob: duplicate type received
```

I tried to rearage the decoder and encoders, the SendMessage is a function with the the encoders

```
func SendMessage(conn net.Conn, messageType int, data interface{}) error {
    // Create a new encoder for writing messages
    encoder := gob.NewEncoder(conn)

    // Encode the message type
    err := encoder.Encode(messageType)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error encoding message type: %v", err)
    }

    // Encode and send the actual data
    err = encoder.Encode(data)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error encoding data: %v", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

But I still have the same problem.
I don't undestand the problem, I send different messages from the client to the server, but if the server sends the Order_Book the Client can't decode it

Comment: You are creating new En- and Decoder. Each new Encoder sends all type information and several Decoder read from the same stream. That cannot work. You have one stream, you need one Encoder and one Decoder.

Comment: What is the best way to fix it?
Can the server send a new struct after a request from the client? And how can I implement it?